# Is it possible to add multiple prices to one product in Woo commerce depending on whether the customer is an individual or a professional?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My client has two customer types (enterprises and individuals), he wants to propose different prices regarding the customer type. This customer type should be defined when the customer creates its account. I still haven't found a solution to do this automatically : after account creation depending on whether the customer said he is an enterprise or an individual, I want that the right price is automatically selected. Do you have any idea of how to do this without a manual user role given ?

Before registration, is it possible de display both prices so that the enterprise also knows what it will have to pay if it registered ?

That would be awesome if you have any idea of plugins doing this or how to code this.

Thanks a lot

Have a good day  !

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Remember that asking for plugins is offtopic and since we are not a free coding service, please add some code you've tried to accomplish your usecase. Otherwise, feel free to hire a freelancer. You can follow our guidelines stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a what will be called a Wholesale User Plugin. There's a handful of them out there that you could look into. It will allow you to set up multiple user roles with different pricing structures.

Comment: You may use `Variable products` and create different variations and add different prices for each variable product.